# Who was this Roman General/figure of authority who, on his deathbed, named these two regrets?

Tags: rome, ancient-rome

In my undergrad I took a Roman History/Culture class and remember the professor mentioning someone who died naming two regrets:

1. He once told a secret to a woman
2. He once spent a day idle/doing nothing

The second of which I find very inspiring. I would like to know the identity of this man/read more about him.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Plutarch's [*Lives*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/674/674-h/674-h.htm#2H_4_0025) says this about [Marcus Cato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato_the_Elder):

> He would likewise say ... and that in his whole life he most repented of
>     three things; one was, that he had trusted a secret to a woman;
>     another, that he went by water when he might have gone by land; the
>     third, that he had remained one whole day without doing any business
>     of moment.

Comment: Good find.  Nicely done.

Comment: Indeed,  nice match! But 2Qs: Was he the only match, or did you stop searching after a 'hit"? 2: I wonder why/how etc land/sea got edited out of the teacher quote, being quite specific also about the total number.? (both, entriely optional though)

Comment: @LаngLаngС  Thanks!  I stopped at the first hit (a quote site google found gave me Cato so then I looked at Plutarch), as it seemed to be the sort of book that had nuggets that would stick in a professor's mind.  I assume the prof himself edited the sea/land thing out of his memory, not the OP.

Comment: This was years ago, so the professor did likely mention the three, but I only remembered the two ‘relatable’ ones.

Comment: To me him not liking to travel by water is weirder than him  being a misogynist and a workaholic, so I'd remember than one longer than the other 2!

Comment: Travel by water was quite dangerous and uncomfortable back then compared to by land.

Comment: @Joe But it was much faster than travelling by land, which doesn’t fit well with the third point about regretting wasting time.

Comment: @MikeScott I think it's safe to assume that " when he might have gone by land" means "when it was practical to go by land."

Comment: @kimchilover: not enough information to call him a misogynist, without knowing whether she kept his confidence, betrayed it, blackmailed him etc. And Plutarch doesn't tell us.

Comment: @smcl You are right, I oversimplified. Sorry about that, Cato.